# node.js win10 puppeteer executablePath string

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer, chromium

I am on windows 10 command prompt with a node.js project that is supposed to use puppeteer to launch chrome and then do some other web crawling things. I have run npm install for this project, but when I run it with `node app.js`, I get an error for 'ERROR: The process "chrome.exe" not found.' , my puppeteer code inits the browser like this:

```
    let args = ["--lang=en-US,en", '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-extensions']
    var exPath = "C:\\Users\\marti\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe"
    var options = {
        executablePath: exPath,
        headless: false,
        args
    };
```

In a different command prompt window if i run `start C:\\Users\\marti\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe` it will open a chromium window perfectly fine. Is there an arg I might be missing for node.js windows 10 command prompt puppeteer ?

Answer (score 2):

Your request should be an asynchronous:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: "C:\\Users\\marti\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe",
    headless: false,
    args: ["--lang=en-US,en", '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-extensions']
});
```

And the function in which you are using puppeteer should be of type `async function`

If the issue still persists try adding `'--disable-dev-shm-usage'` argument to args.